# ActiveX Component Can't Create Object

Tags: vb.net, vb6, activex

I have VB6 ActiveXDLL called `A.dll` , I am referencing this DLL into my VB.Net Application.

Now I am calling a function of A.dll in this project. `A.dll` function is referring to the function of `B.dll`, `C.dll`, `C.dll` further referrer to `Z.dll` and so on.

when I am executing application it gives an error from B.dll that ActiveX component can't create an object.

Comment: Check file permissions - if you're in a development environment loosen them to test. Also check the Windows registry settings for it. That's all I can recollect right now.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to make sure all dlls are registered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ActiveX DLL is VB6 and you have access to the VB6 IDE, ensure the class's `Instancing` property is set to `Multiuse`.

Answer (score 0):

Use OLE View (comes with visual studio) to browse ther TypeLib entry and check it has the correct GUID and that there is onely one registration. Can you create an object instance from the DLL with CreateObject? If not it is not registered correctly.

Comment: If there is more than one entry, right click each one and select Copy GUID to CLipboard, then search the registry fro that key and delete the key (and all sub keys) that is has the saem name as the GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Also check any dependencies / references used by A.dll
If it can't find something then it's going to fail.

These are the four common causes of the error:
   1.  You do not have a required TLB or ActiveX DLL/OCX file.
   2. A TLB or ActiveX DLL/OCX needed by the project is present but not registered on your system.
   3. The VB runtimes are an earlier version than the one you need to run the project.
   4. A required TLB or ActiveX DLL/OCX file is corrupt.